# RPG, sistema de combate por turnos, enemigo no ataca

Tags: unity3d, unity2d

Decidí comenzar a hacer un RPG, así que aprendí a usar maquinas de estado. El problema es que al probarlas, el enemigo debugea constantemente su daño, así que decidí añadir llamados al estado `WAITING`, tanto en el héroe como en el enemigo. Ahora el enemigo jamás ataca, ¿hay alguna forma de solucionar esto?

Aquí esta mi **máquina de estado de batalla**:

```
using UnityEngine; using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic; using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BattleState : MonoBehaviour {

 public enum performAction
 {
     WAIT,
     TAKEACTION,
     PERFORMACTION
 }
 public performAction battleStates;
 public List<HandleTurn> PerformList = new List<HandleTurn>();//lista de actores
 public List<GameObject> HeroInGame = new List<GameObject>();//heroes en la escena
 public List<GameObject> EnemiesInBattle = new List<GameObject>();//enemigos en la escena
 public enum HeroGUi//acciones posibles del heroe
 {
     ACTIVATE,
     WAITING,
     INPUT1,
     INPUT2,
     DONE
 }
 public HeroGUi HeroInput;
 public List<GameObject> HeroesToManage = new List<GameObject>();
 private HandleTurn HeroChoice;
 public GameObject enemyButton;
 public Transform Spacer;
 public GameObject AttackPanel;
 public GameObject EnemySelectPanel;
 public GameObject StatusPanel;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start ()
 {
     battleStates = performAction.WAIT;
     EnemiesInBattle.AddRange(GameObject.FindGa

meObjectsWithTag("Enemy"));
     HeroInGame.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Hero"));
     HeroInput = HeroGUi.ACTIVATE;
     AttackPanel.SetActive(false);
     EnemySelectPanel.SetActive(false);
     StatusPanel.SetActive(false);
     CreateEnemyButtons();

 }
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update ()
 {
     if (HeroSM.inBattle == true)
     {
         StatusPanel.SetActive(true);
             switch (battleStates)
             {
             case (performAction.WAIT):
                 if (PerformList.Count > 0)//revisa la lista
                 {
                     battleStates = performAction.TAKEACTION;
                 }
             break;
             case (performAction.TAKEACTION):
                 GameObject performer = GameObject.Find(PerformList[0].Attacker);
                 if (PerformList[0].Side == "Enemy")
                 {                     
                     EnemySM ESM = performer.GetComponent<EnemySM>();
                     ESM.HeroToAttack = PerformList[0].TargetGO;
                     EnemySM.currentEnemyTurn = EnemySM.enemyTurn.ACTION;
                     HeroSM.currentHeroTurn = HeroSM.heroTurn.WAITING;
                 }
                 if (PerformList[0].Side == "Hero")
                 {

                     HeroSM HSM = performer.GetComponent<HeroSM>();
                     HSM.EnemyToAttack = PerformList[0].TargetGO;
                     HeroSM.currentHeroTurn = HeroSM.heroTurn.ACTION;
                     EnemySM.currentEnemyTurn = EnemySM.enemyTurn.WAITING;
                 }
                 battleStates = performAction.PERFORMACTION;
             break;
             case (performAction.PERFORMACTION):
                 //iddle
             break;
             }
         //switch para el estado del heroe



             switch (HeroInput)
             {
                 case (HeroGUi.ACTIVATE):
                     if (HeroesToManage.Count > 0)
                     {
                         print("im active yo!");
                         HeroesToManage[0].transform.FindChild("Selector").gameObject.SetActive(true);//tomamos al primer heroe de la lista, hallamos el padre, pasamos al hijo llamado selector y seteamos el booleano
                         HeroChoice = new HandleTurn();
                         AttackPanel.SetActive(true);
                         HeroInput = HeroGUi.WAITING;
                     }
                 break;
                 case (HeroGUi.WAITING):
                     //iddle
                 break;
                 case (HeroGUi.DONE):
                     HeroInputDone();
                 break;
             }
     }
 }
 public void CollectActions(HandleTurn handleInput)
 {
     PerformList.Add(handleInput);
 }
 void CreateEnemyButtons ()
 {
     foreach(GameObject Enemy in EnemiesInBattle)
     {
         GameObject newButton = Instantiate(enemyButton) as GameObject;
         EnemySelectButton button = newButton.GetComponent<EnemySelectButton>();
         EnemySM curEnemy = Enemy.GetComponent<EnemySM>();
         Text buttonText = newButton.transform.FindChild("Text").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
         buttonText.text = curEnemy.Enemy.baseName;
         button.EnemyPrefab = Enemy;
         newButton.transform.SetParent(Spacer, false);
     }
 }
 public void Input1()//attack button
 {
     HeroChoice.Attacker = HeroesToManage[0].name;
     HeroChoice.AttackerGO = HeroesToManage[0]; // ya es un gameobject asi que no lo especificamos
     HeroChoice.Side = "Hero";
     AttackPanel.SetActive(false);
     EnemySelectPanel.SetActive(true);
 }
 public void InputEnemySelection(GameObject choosenEnemy)//enemy selection
 {
     HeroChoice.TargetGO = choosenEnemy;
     HeroInput = HeroGUi.DONE;
 }
 void HeroInputDone()
 {
     PerformList.Add(HeroChoice);
     EnemySelectPanel.SetActive(false);
     AttackPanel.SetActive(true);
     HeroesToManage[0].transform.FindChild("Selector").gameObject.SetActive(false);
     HeroesToManage.RemoveAt(0);
     HeroInput = HeroGUi.ACTIVATE;
 }
}
```

Esta es la **máquina de estado del enemigo**:

```
using UnityEngine; using System.Collections; using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemySM : MonoBehaviour {

 public EnemyStats Enemy;//creamos a enemigo desde la plantilla
 private BattleState BS;
 public bool actionStarted = false;
 public GameObject Description;

 public enum enemyTurn
 {
     PROCESSING,
     CHOOSEACTION,
     WAITING,
     ACTION,
     DEAD
 }
 public static enemyTurn currentEnemyTurn;

 //para cambiar las barras
 private float curHealth;
 public GameObject HeroToAttack;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start()
 {
     currentEnemyTurn = enemyTurn.WAITING;
     BS = GameObject.Find("BM").GetComponent<BattleState>();

 }
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
    /* if (HeroSM.currentHeroTurn != HeroSM.heroTurn.WAITING)
     {
         currentEnemyTurn = enemyTurn.WAITING;
     }*/

     if (GMScript.InBattle == true)
     {
         curHealth = Enemy.CurrentHp;
         switch (currentEnemyTurn)
         {
             case (enemyTurn.PROCESSING):
                 print("enemy processing");
                 currentEnemyTurn = enemyTurn.CHOOSEACTION;

                 break;
             case (enemyTurn.CHOOSEACTION):
                 print("enemy chooseaction");
                 ChooseAction();
                 currentEnemyTurn = enemyTurn.WAITING;

                 break;
             case (enemyTurn.WAITING):
                 //idle state
                 /*if (HeroSM.currentHeroTurn == HeroSM.heroTurn.WAITING)
                 {
                     currentEnemyTurn = enemyTurn.PROCESSING;
                 }*/
                 break;
             case (enemyTurn.ACTION):
                 print("enemy action");
                 StartCoroutine(TimeForAction());

                 break;
             case (enemyTurn.DEAD):
                 break;
         }
     }
 }
 void ChooseAction()
 {        
     HandleTurn myAttack = new HandleTurn();
     myAttack.Attacker = Enemy.baseName;
     myAttack.Side = "Enemy";
     myAttack.AttackerGO = this.gameObject;
     myAttack.TargetGO = BS.HeroInGame[Random.Range(0, BS.HeroInGame.Count)];
     int num = Random.Range(0,Enemy.Attacks.Count);//se genra un numero aleatorio entre 0 y la cantidad de ataques
     myAttack.chooseAttack = Enemy.Attacks[num];//usamos el numero para escoger el ataque
     Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + " has choosen " + myAttack.chooseAttack.attackName + " and did " +myAttack.chooseAttack.attackDamage + " damage!!!");
     BS.CollectActions(myAttack);
 }
 private IEnumerator TimeForAction ()//controla variables atraves del tiempo
 {
     if(actionStarted == true)
     {
         yield break;
     }
     actionStarted = true;
     //wait
     //do damage
    DoDamage();
     //remove from bs list
     BS.PerformList.RemoveAt(0);//remueve al objeto en 0, el siguiente sube transformando el 1 en 0
     //continua removiendo hasta desaparecer todo
     //reset bs to wait
     BS.battleStates = BattleState.performAction.WAIT;
     //al pasar a wait y saltar a takeaction los objetos vuelven a crearse repitiendo el ciclo
     //end coroutine
     actionStarted = false;
     currentEnemyTurn = enemyTurn.PROCESSING;
 }
 void DoDamage()
 {
     float calcDamage = Enemy.Fue * BS.PerformList[0].chooseAttack.attackDamage;
     HeroToAttack.GetComponent<HeroSM>().TakeDamage(calcDamage);
 }

}
```

Esta es la **máquina de estado del héroe**:

```
using UnityEngine; using System.Collections; using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HeroSM : MonoBehaviour {

 private BattleState BS;
 public static bool inBattle;
 public partyStat hero;//creamos a hero desde la plantilla

 public enum heroTurn
 {
     START,
     PROCESSING,
     ADDTOLIST,
     WAITING,
     SELECTING,
     ACTION,
     DEAD
 }

 public static heroTurn currentHeroTurn;
 //para cambiar las barras
 private float curHealth;
 public Image healthB;
 public Image chamaB;
 public GameObject selector;
 public GameObject EnemyToAttack;
 //ienumerator
 private bool actionStarted;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start ()
 {
     selector.SetActive(false);
     BS = GameObject.Find("BM").GetComponent<BattleState>();
     currentHeroTurn = heroTurn.START;

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update ()
 {
     /*if (EnemySM.currentEnemyTurn != EnemySM.enemyTurn.WAITING)
     {
         currentHeroTurn = heroTurn.WAITING;
     }*/

     //creamos el movimiento de las barras de hp y chama
     chamaB.transform.localScale = new Vector3(hero.CurrentChama / 100, this.transform.localScale.y, this.transform.localScale.z);
     healthB.transform.localScale = new Vector3(hero.CurrentHp / 100, this.transform.localScale.y, this.transform.localScale.z);
     curHealth = hero.CurrentHp;
     if (GMScript.InBattle == true)
     {
         switch (currentHeroTurn)
         {
             case (heroTurn.START):

                 currentHeroTurn = heroTurn.PROCESSING;
                 break;
             case (heroTurn.PROCESSING):
                 //inBattle = true;
                 //print("hero processing");
                 UpgradeBar();
                 break;
             case (heroTurn.ADDTOLIST):
                 //print("hero addtolist");
                 BS.HeroesToManage.Add(this.gameObject);
                 currentHeroTurn = heroTurn.WAITING;
                 break;
             case (heroTurn.WAITING):
                 //print("hero waiting");
                /* if (EnemySM.currentEnemyTurn == EnemySM.enemyTurn.WAITING)
                 {
                     currentHeroTurn = heroTurn.START;
                 }*/
                 //idle
                 break;
             case (heroTurn.ACTION):
                 //print("hero action");
                 StartCoroutine(TimeForAction());
                 break;
             case (heroTurn.DEAD):
                 break;
         }
     }    
 }
 void UpgradeBar()
 {
     currentHeroTurn = heroTurn.ADDTOLIST;
 }
 private IEnumerator TimeForAction()//controla variables atraves del tiempo
 {
     if (actionStarted == true)
     {
         yield break;
     }
     actionStarted = true;
     //wait
     //do damage
     //remove from bs list
     BS.PerformList.RemoveAt(0);//remueve al objeto en 0, el siguiente sube transformando el 1 en 0
     //continua removiendo hasta desaparecer todo
     //reset bs to wait
     BS.battleStates = BattleState.performAction.WAIT;
     //al pasar a wait y saltar a takeaction los objetos vuelven a crearse repitiendo el ciclo
     //end coroutine
     actionStarted = false;
     currentHeroTurn = heroTurn.PROCESSING;
 }
 public void TakeDamage(float getDamageAmount)
 {
     hero.CurrentHp -= getDamageAmount;
     if (hero.CurrentHp <= 0)
     {
         currentHeroTurn = heroTurn.DEAD;
     }
 }
}
```

Cualquier dato será de ayuda.

Comment: UPDATE: no change seems to fix it but i habe noticed that the heroes to manage only adds my first hero making the same hero turn time and time again, maeby this is conected to the other problem somehow?